# Change the "How to ask" section

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-deferred, asking-questions

If you ask a question there is a section on how to ask in the sidebar, currently this looks like the following:

> How To Ask
>
> Is your question about scientific skepticism? We prefer questions that
>   can be answered, not just discussed. Provide details. Share your
>   research. If your question is about this website, ask it on meta
>   instead.
>
> Read The Faq »
>
> Asking Help »

This is not optimal for our site in my opinion, and I think it would be a good place to put our requirements for notability. We should adapt the first sentence, as the site is not really about scientific skepticism itself, but about applying skepticism. And a short sentence on notability with a link to the longer explanation (e.g. the new user welcome meta post) would be useful as well.

Any suggestions on what else we should change, or how to exactly formulate it? We should try to avoid making it significantly longer than it currently is, or even fewer people will read it.

Comment: We are currently working on the help sections. It doesn't make any sense changing the current ones until these changes are deployed. I think it's still useful to have this discussion, though.

Comment: Adjusting the text for this is pretty trivial, although as @Sklivvz notes we *might* be changing it again soon anyway. Hash out what you'd like changed and we'll work it in somewhere.